# Mongodb install fails in Ubuntu 14.04 docker container

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, docker, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb on ubuntu 14.04 in a docker container, using the following steps from the official mongodb guides in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install \
    nodejs\
    npm \
    git \
    mongodb-org
```

These commands install mongodb properly on my host ubuntu system, but not in docker. In my docker image, /etc/init.d/mongod is not there. The following error is printed while running "docker build":

```
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongod not found.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

Comment: This looks like you are installing the Ubuntu 14.04 version of the package (so upstart based) but then trying to run it with the SysV init style scripts.  What is the base OS image of the container, and what is actually getting installed by using `lsb_release -sc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ref: [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733201/mongodb-is-not-starting-in-ubuntu)

As mentioned from above, the reason is that you are trying to install a version packaged for Upstart init services, but ubuntu 14.04 still uses SysV init by default. The recommended approach is to use later version 3.2.x from [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=1.245982924.932630465.1451894386#install-the-mongodb-packages) or if you are strict about the version, the fix is to use

```
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen
```

instead of

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse
```

Also, to get the mongod running when launching with *docker run -d*, you need to add a CMD to it.
So, I modified and compiled a docker file to test this and looked like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10 \
  && echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list \
  && apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install \
    nodejs\
    npm \
    git \
    mongodb-org 

CMD ["mongod", "--dbpath", "."]
```

Note that, I didn't use the init to start the container as the init script places the mongod in the background (in addition to many other things). For docker containers to run continuously, the CMD script should be in foreground.

A clip from /etc/init.d/mongod *start()* note the **--background** there

```
    # Start the process using the wrapper
    start-stop-daemon --background --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
                --make-pidfile --chuid $DAEMONUSER \
                --exec $NUMACTL $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
```

Comment: This is such a wonderfully complete answer. Thank you.